# Wrap a contact form around background image

Tags: css, html, center

How do I wrap a contact form around a backgroud image (eg. a desktop screen). For further clarification, please visit this [link](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/). Scroll down to the bottom of the page and you'll see a mac screen background wraped inside of a login page.

```
<div id="new_div_3">
        <form class="contact_form" action="#" method="post" name="contact_form">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                    <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text"  placeholder="John Doe" required />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required />
                    <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="website">Website:</label>
                    <input type="url" name="website" placeholder="http://johndoe.com" required pattern="(http|https)://.+"/>
                    <span class="form_hint">Proper format "http://someaddress.com"</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="message">Message:</label>
                    <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6" required ></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This is what i currently have in my `new_div_3`.

```
#new_div_3 {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    background:#ECF0F1 url('img/email-screen.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 1040px 878px;
    padding: 38px 38px 267px;
}
```

Is there a way of making the background appear correctly, in the center of the div with the addition of the contact form appearing in the center too?

Comment: Your question title is misleading. Are you asking how to centralise the background image?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
background:#ECF0F1 url('img/email-screen.png') no-repeat center center;
```

If you are using firefox or chrome, you can use inspect element to see how it has been setup in the example you provided.